# Example where article reverses meaning

Tags: grammar, articles

Adding "the" reverses the meaning in these two sentences:

- Alice is in charge of Bob.
- Alice is in **the** charge of Bob.

What is the formal grammatical explanation of this difference?

Answer (score 2):

*In charge of* is a complex preposition like *in place of*, *in spite of*, *in view of*, or *in case of*. It means having responsibility for or jurisdiction over someone or something. *In the charge of* is a preposition phrase meaning in the care or custody of someone.

A similar change in meaning occurs when the definite article is inserted into the complex preposition *in view of*. *In view of* means *because of* and *in the view of* means *in the opinion of*.

And *She was sitting in front of the car* (complex preposition) has a different meaning from *She was sitting in the front of the car* (preposition phrase).

---

ADDENDUM:

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p616) contests the traditional designation of *complex prepositions* for phrases such as *in charge of, by dint of*. It refers to them instead as *idiomatic and fossilised expressions headed by a preposition*.

The CGEL then uses various syntactic tests to compare such idiomatic expressions to prepositional phrases that permit what it calls *free expression*. So, for example, the [bracketed] free expression *She put it [on the photo of her son]* permits the full range of syntactic manipulations, including:

> She has lost [the photo of her son]. (occurrence without preposition)
>
> She put in [on her son's photo]. (genitive alternation).

The most fossilized expressions permit none of the nine syntactic manipulations allowed of free expressions. The CGEL lists *in case of, by dint of, by means of* among the completely fossilized expressions.

*In charge of*  is an example of a less fossilized phrase that permits some manipulation, but not all. For example, it permits modification of the noun (eg. *in full charge of*), but not omission of the head preposition (**She was put charge of the orphans*).

As a free expression, *in the charge of* permits all the syntactic manipulations. The CGEL notes elsewhere that the preposition *of* in a free expression such as *They were mourning the death of their king* has  *no identifiable meaning independent of the grammatical structure in which it occurs*. Such *grammaticised uses ... serve the same function as inflection cases*. Hence, *the death of the king* is equivalent *to the king's death*.

So, as Op notes in the comment below, *in the charge of Bob* is equivalent to *in Bob's charge*, and similar to *in Bob's care*, *in Bob's power, in Bob's custody*. The reason why the definite article is used in the free expression *in the charge of* is the same reason it is used in any such genitive construction.

And the reason that *in the charge of Bob* reverses the meaning of *in charge of Bob* is that the semi-fossilized idiomatic expression *in charge of* means *responsible **for** or having jurisdiction over* (an active role), whereas the noun *charge* in the free expression *in the charge of* means care or custody, and is equivalent to *being the responsibility **of*** (a passive role).

Comment: My interest here is in the rules for the use of articles in English (to tease my Slavic friends) and wanted to note this example somewhere.   You have stated the meanings of my two sentences, but I wonder whether you could offer a theoretical explanation of why inserting the article changes (reverses) the meaning?

Comment: I agree that the whole phrase "*in charge of*" is a preposition, but I think that "*in the charge of Bob*" consists of a simple preposition (in) together with the possessive phrase "*the charge of Bob*" (= "*Bob's charge*"). What I still don't see is why the article switches from one to the other.

Comment: @Paul, In _The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_ there is a lengthy analysis of complex prepositions such as _in charge of_. In fact, the CGEL favours referring to them as _idiomatic and fossilised expressions headed by a preposition_. I'll include a summary of this analysis when I have more time tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the sophisticated explanation, in particular that the first expression is semi-fossilised but the second is free.  However, your final paragraph re-stated my original question: why does the insertion of the **article** take one expression to another with the opposite meaning?  Is this any more than idiomatic accident?  It was the behaviour of articles in English that interested me, rather than prepositions.

Comment: @Paul, I think the point is that the definite article is not being inserted into _in charge of_, _a semi-fossilised idiomatic expression headed by a preposition_. But rather that it is being used in a typical construction that is equivalent to a genitive with an apostrophe. We need _the_ in this construction in the same way that we need it in _the death of the king_ or _the power of love_. The reversal of meaning in this case is a result of the two opposite senses of _charge_ in the two expressions: _in charge of (having responsibility for)_ and _in the charge of (in the responsibility of)_.

Comment: You still seem to be saying that it's just an idiomatic accident.  Yet the word *charge* has the same meaning, but active in *in charge* and passive in *the charge*.  I am trying to understand how the article causes this difference.

Comment: @Paul, this has been an interesting exchange but I am at the end of my explanatory powers! Maybe you could post a new question specifically addressing the issue that I have failed to answer.